# PTIJ: According to Rava, who is the seventh prophetess?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Megillah 14a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.14a.13?lang=bi) states that there were seven prophetesses, and lists them as:

1. Sarah
2. Miriam
3. Deborah
4. Hannah
5. Abigail
6. Huldah
7. Esther

But Rava in [Pesachim 9b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.9b.7?lang=bi) asks rhetorically:

> And is Huldah a prophetess?

So, if Huldah is not a prophetess, who does Rava believe to be the seventh prophetess?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Ah, it's that time of year again...:) Chodesh tov!

Comment: Actually I think that was Rava's joke.

Comment: First time I read this gemara, I said out loud: וכי חולדה נביאה היא? אין, חולדה נביאה היא...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rava's fellow Talmudic sage Rav Nachman [identifies](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.14b.10) the prophetess of the Huldah narrative as one enigmatic "Karkoshta." Anyone schooled in Aramaic will recognize that that this name means City-And-Year (כרכ-ושתא). Rashi comments there that Karkoshta is Huldah, evidently taking her name to mean "World - Year 5" (חלד-ה), but there is a likelier interpretation in light of the [original verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.22.14):

> וַיֵּלֶךְ חִלְקִיָּהוּ הַכֹּהֵן וַאֲחִיקָם וְעַכְבּוֹר וְשָׁפָן וַעֲשָׂיָה אֶל חֻלְדָּה הַנְּבִיאָה אֵשֶׁת שַׁלֻּם בֶּן תִּקְוָה בֶּן חַרְחַס שֹׁמֵר הַבְּגָדִים וְהִיא יֹשֶׁבֶת בִּירוּשָׁלַ‍ִם בַּמִּשְׁנֶה וַיְדַבְּרוּ אֵלֶיהָ
>
> And Hilkiah the Priest and Ahikam and Achbor and Shaphan and Asaiah went to Huldah the prophetess, the wife of Shallum son of Tikvah son of Harhas, the guardian of the clothes. And she was sitting with *Jerusalem-From-Year*. And they spoke with ***her***.

Of course, Rav Nachman (and Rava) understand that they spoke with Jerusalem-From-Year (a.k.a. City-And-Year), not with Huldah.

Answer (score 1):

We follow R. Ami's opinion in Taanis 8a, that Huldah is in fact a messenger for the word of God:

> המאמין בחולדה ובור כך המאמין בהקב"ה
>
> One who believes in Huldah (and Bore), does then believe in the Holy One Blessed be He.

Answer (score 0):

Rava in Pesachim 9b was arguing on Abaye. However clearly Abaye held Chulda was a prophetess. Therefore you can say the gemara in megilla 14a is going according to Abaye. This would mean Rava held there were only 6 prophetesses.